# Mysql Optimization - Each User stores a lot of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making a web application using php and mysql that allows a user to enter data over time.  When I think of how to structure the data, it would make sense to have a separate table for each user structured like this: (see below, not including (user) column). I know that making a separate table for each user is not a good idea from other posts, so I'm wondering how to structure the data. My other thought was to have another column for each user.  When I want to retrieve the past 10 days entries I could just do `SELECT Value1, Value2 WHERE DATE="1/1/14", USER="dave"`. That way would seem to work, but if my application has, say, 10000 users, each logging, say 10 values at a time, I could get a huge table.  That may not be a problem, as I guess mySQL may be optimized for that, but I just want to get another opinion on the best way.

```
Date    Value1  Value2  Value3       (user)
1/1/14  1       1       2            (dave)
1/2/14  2       2       2            (dave)
1/2/14  2       2       1            (tom)
1/3/14  3       2       2            (dave)
```

Comment: 100,000 rows is not a huge table.  SQL is designed to handle lots of data, so the one-table solution is the right way to go in almost all circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon said above: 100,000 isn't a huge table. Even a million rows is easily handled by a properly indexed table.

How I would handle this:

If each user has static fields (every user has the same fields), create a table like so:

```
USER_ID
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3
FIELD4
```

Where the primary key is the USER_ID.

If each user has dynamic fields:

```
USER_ID
FIELD_NAME
VALUE
```

Where the primary key is a composite key of USER_ID,FIELD_NAME.  This way you could store the value of any field you desire for that user and you could have multiple rows/fields for each user.

Comment: Do you have any more information on dynamic fields?  Would I do that by just storing a json object?  Also what would would it mean to have a composite key of two different fields?

Comment: @user3413723 . . . "dynamic fields" in this case refers to an entity-attribute-value (EAV) structure.  You can google this.

Comment: @user3413723, you store each field and value pair in a separate row.  I don't recommend storing JSON objects, serialized arrays, etc unless it matches a very specific purpose.  When you store multiple values in one field like that, then you hamper the ability to search for specific values.  For instance it makes it hard to search for a specific field, get one value from the table, or determine if a value is defined.

Comment: So with the dynamic fields, instead of having 10 rows with a user id and 10 values each, I'd have 100 rows with a user id, value key, and value in each one.  Is that right?  I think for the application I'm doing I will be able to use the one row 10 values method though, but its good to know in case I need to make something like that in the future.

Comment: @user3413723 Yes that is right.  If the ten fields are shared for all users, then it makes much more sense to use my first example.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it in one table. Don't do the table-per-user way.  Also, don't use the reserved word `DATE` or `USER` for a column name, instead column names like `ENTRY_DATE` and `USERNAME`.

EDIT: Here's what I'm thinking, a normalized schema that allows dynamic fields.  Play with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54b5b/3/0

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id      INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , name    VARCHAR(100)
  , email   VARCHAR(100)
  -- and whatever other user info you want to keep
);

CREATE TABLE measures (
    id    INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , name  VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE measure_facts (
    id         INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , entry_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  , user_id    INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
  , measure_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES measures(id) 
  , value      INTEGER 
  , KEY (user_id, entry_date, measure_id)
);

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('dave'), ('tom');

INSERT INTO measures (name) VALUES ('measure1'), ('measure2'), ('measure3');

INSERT INTO measure_facts (user_id, entry_date, measure_id, value) VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01', 1, 1)
  , (1, '2014-01-01', 2, 1)
  , (1, '2014-01-01', 3, 2)

  , (1, '2014-01-02', 1, 2)
  , (1, '2014-01-02', 2, 2)
  , (1, '2014-01-02', 3, 2)

  , (2, '2014-01-02', 1, 2)
  , (2, '2014-01-02', 2, 2)
  , (2, '2014-01-02', 3, 1)

  , (1, '2014-01-03', 1, 3)
  , (1, '2014-01-03', 2, 2)
  , (1, '2014-01-03', 3, 1);
```

and then a query:

```
SELECT entry_date, m.name measure_name, value, u.name user_name
  FROM measure_facts
  JOIN measures m ON (measure_id = m.id) 
  JOIN users    u ON (   user_id = u.id);
```